# NiFi - Configure Maximum Threads Automatically

Tags: docker, automation, apache-nifi

I'm running NiFi 1.3.0 on a Docker image in DCOS. When the image gets redeployed after an automated build, the maximum threads get reset to 10 for timer processors and 5 for event processors. I have to manually set these where I want them after every redeploy. Is there a way to configure these via nifi.properties or in the template.xml? Some other location? The user manual only references the manual GUI option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`conf/flow.xml.gz` -> `flow.xml`

```
<flowController encoding-version="1.1">
  <maxTimerDrivenThreadCount>10</maxTimerDrivenThreadCount>
  <maxEventDrivenThreadCount>5</maxEventDrivenThreadCount>
  ...
```